# How to assertThat a list of objects has a set of properties with certain values

Tags: java, testing, hamcrest

Using the Hamcrest library, I need to assert that a list of objects with specific properties (java beans) matches a set of properties. For example, if we had a list of Person objects with firstName, lastName, and middleName properties I've tried the following:

```
assertThat(personObjectList, either(contains(
      hasProperty("firstName", is("Bob")),
      hasProperty("lastName", is("Smith")),
      hasProperty("middleName", is("R.")))
.or(contains(
      hasProperty("firstName", is("Alex")),
      hasProperty("lastName", is("Black")),
      hasProperty("middleName", is("T."))));
```

But in execution the properties of the objects are not obtained, I just get a comparison against the Object T, output like:

> but: was Person@7bd7c4cf, was Person@5b9df3b3

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here using Hamcrest? This works when doing a single contains, but when doing two contains with either() I receive the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `anyOf` [method](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/AnyOf.html#anyOf(org.hamcrest.Matcher...)). For example:

```
List<Person> persins = Arrays.asList( new Person("Bob", "Smith", "R."));

assertThat(persons, contains(anyOf(
      sameProprtyValues(new Person("Bob", "Smith", "R.")),
      sameProprtyValues(new Person("Alex", "Black", "T.")) 
));
```

If you want to use several properties, you should try:

```
assertThat(persons, contains(
    either(
            both(hasProperty("firstName", is("Bob")))
            .and(hasProperty("lastName", is("Smith")))
            .and(hasProperty("middleName", is("R.")))
    ).or(
            both(hasProperty("firstName", is("Alex")))
            .and(hasProperty("lastName", is("Black")))
            .and(hasProperty("middleName", is("T.")))
    )
));
```

Comment: I'm using a schema which will not allow me to overload the constructor for the Object. Is there any other way to accomplish this without giving the parameters in the constructor?

Comment: Above, I tried to describe how to use any fields for compare objects.